# SWT table: listener for resized or moved column

Tags: java, swt

How my code can be notified if the user resized or moved a table column?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a `ControlAdapter` via `TableColumn.addControlListener()` and overwrite `void controlResized(ControlEvent e)`