# SWT: Listener for table column resize

Tags: swt, listener

I have the following layout

[image]

where the idea is to make the table filterable by just typing text into the filter Text fields at the top (this code part is not depicted below).

The usage should be such that the filters match the corresponding columns in width and when scrolling horizontally, both the table and the filter fields should move so that the correspondence between the filter and its column is staying.

I have the following questions:

1. If the user resizes a column, what kind of listener do I need to attach to get notified in order to resize the filter fields so that they match the new column width (so alignFilter() can be called)?
2. I made a hack for both the height and width of the filter fields ("// hack" nearly at the bottom), how can this be made cleaner?
3. And finally, when scrolling the table, the filter fields will be scrolled off the visible area so in order to filter text, one has to scroll up. How could the layout be changed such that the filter fields stay visible?

```java
public class FilteredTable {

private final static int numColumns = 20;
private static Text filter[];
private static Table table;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    // Outer area with scrollbars
    final ScrolledComposite scrollArea = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    scrollArea.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    scrollArea.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    // Inner area to hold in its first row the filter fields and in its second row the table
    final Composite content = new Composite(scrollArea, SWT.NONE);
    final GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(numColumns, false);
    gridLayout.marginLeft = 0;
    gridLayout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
    content.setLayout(gridLayout);
    content.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    // First row: text filters
    filter = new Text[numColumns];
    for (int i=0; i < numColumns; i++) {

        filter[i] = new Text(content, SWT.BORDER);
        filter[i].setText("Filter " + i);
    }

    // Second row: table
    table = new Table(content, SWT.NO_SCROLL);
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults()
    .grab(true, true)
    .span(numColumns, 1)
    .applyTo(table);

    String heading = "";
    for (int col = 0; col < numColumns; col++) {
        heading += "o";
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        column.setText(heading);
    }
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    scrollArea.setContent(content);
    scrollArea.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrollArea.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrollArea.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
    scrollArea.setMinSize(table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

    // Test data
    for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++)  {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);

        for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
            item.setText(col, row + "." + col);
        }
    }

    for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        table.getColumn(col).pack();
    }

    scrollArea.setMinSize(table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

    alignFilter();

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400, 300);

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void alignFilter() {
    for (int i=0; i < filter.length; i++) {
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults()
        .grab(false, false)
        .hint(table.getColumn(i).getWidth()-(i==0 ? 11 : 12), 20) // Hack
        .applyTo(filter[i]);
        filter[i].pack();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The question regarding column resize listeners is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357270/swt-table-listener-for-resized-or-moved-column

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one Question, you will end up just getting comments about the individual questions. If you can use JFace using an extended `TableColumnLayout` overriding `setColumnWidths` can deal with aligning a header.

Comment: Regarding the filter input field layout, you may want to look into TableEditor::layout. It uses TableItem::getBounds to align with columns. For empty tables a temporary item (within a setRedraw false/true block) may be necessary. With table.computeTrim() the client area offset can be determined.